# spray-json and list marshalling

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, spray, spray-json

I'm using spray-json to marshal lists of custom objects into JSON. I have the following case class and its JsonProtocol.

```
case class ElementResponse(name: String, symbol: String, code: String, pkwiu: String, remarks: String, priceNetto: BigDecimal, priceBrutto: BigDecimal, vat: Int, minInStock:Int,                        maxInStock: Int)

object JollyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol with SprayJsonSupport  {
 implicit val elementFormat = jsonFormat10(ElementResponse)
}
```

When I try to put in in a route like this one:

```
get {
      complete {
        List(new ElementResponse(...), new ElementResponse(...))
      }
    }
```

I get an error saying that:

```
 could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type spray.httpx.marshalling.Marshaller[List[pl.ftang.scala.polka.rest.ElementResponse]]
```

Perhaps you know what is the problem?

I'm using Scala 2.10.1 with spray 1.1-M7 and spray-json 1.2.5

Comment: See [this example](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/examples/spray-client/simple-spray-client/src/main/scala/spray/examples/Main.scala), which uses a ```List```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to import the format you defined on the route scope:

```
import JollyJsonProtocol._
get {
      complete {
        List(new ElementResponse(...), new ElementResponse(...))
      }
    }
```

Comment: I have that import. Marshalling objects of type ElementResponse works fine. What does not work is marshalling Lists of those objects.

Answer (score 5):

*This is an old issue, but I feel like giving my 2c. Was looking at similar issues today.*

Marcin, it seems your issue was not actually solved (as far as I can read) - why did you accept one answer?

Did you try adding `import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._` in places? Those are in charge of making things such as `Seq`s, `Map`s, `Option`s and `Tuple`s to work. I would assume this might be the cause of your problem, since it's the `List` that is not getting converted.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this, is to make a String from your list or you'll have to deal with ChunckedMessages:

```
implicit def ListMarshaller[T](implicit m: Marshaller[T]) =
    Marshaller[List[T]]{ (value, ctx) =>
      value match {
        case Nil => ctx.marshalTo(EmptyEntity)
        case v => v.map(m(_, ctx)).mkString(",")
      }
    }
```

The seconds way is to convert your list into the `Stream[ElementResponse]` and let spray [chunck](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-httpx/src/main/scala/spray/httpx/marshalling/MetaMarshallers.scala#L59) it for you.

```
get {
  complete {
    List(new ElementResponse(...), new ElementResponse(...)).toStream
  }
}
```

Comment: That is a nice idea, but how should I use marshaller in my json protocol? (JollyJsonProtocol in my case) - adding this implicit method to the protocol class does not help.

Comment: I would recommend you to rename your JollyJsonProtocol and make it as a companion object for [import tax][2]. List marshaller should work by importing it into the scope. As for `Stream` just call `toStream` on your list