# could not find implicit value for parameter marshaller: spray.httpx.marshalling.ToResponseMarshaller

Tags: scala, spray, spray-json

I'm using

```
val akkaV = "2.2.3"
val sprayV = "1.2.0"
Seq(
  "io.spray"            %   "spray-can"     % sprayV,
  "io.spray"            %   "spray-routing" % sprayV,
  "io.spray"          %%  "spray-json"    % "1.2.5",
  "io.spray"            %   "spray-testkit" % sprayV,
  "com.typesafe.akka"   %%  "akka-actor"    % akkaV,
  "com.typesafe.akka"   %%  "akka-testkit"  % akkaV,
```

And getting this error:

> could not find implicit value for parameter marshaller: spray.httpx.marshalling.ToResponseMarshaller[List[org.bwi.models.Cluster]]

with this code:

```
object JsonImplicits extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
val impCluster = jsonFormat2(Cluster)

}

trait ToolsService extends HttpService with spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport {

val myRoute = {

    import JsonImplicits._

    path("") { get { getFromResource("tools.html") } } ~
        pathPrefix("css") { get { getFromResourceDirectory("css") } } ~
        pathPrefix("fonts") { get { getFromResourceDirectory("fonts") } } ~
        pathPrefix("js") { get { getFromResourceDirectory("js") } } ~
        path("clusters") {
            get {
                complete {
                    val result: List[Cluster] = List(Cluster("1", "1 d"), Cluster("2", "2 d"), Cluster("3", "3 d"))
                    result //*****   ERROR OCCURS HERE *****
                }
            }
        }
}
```

}

I've tried the suggestion [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734457/spray-json-and-list-marshalling?rq=1) but it did not work, same error.

I can't seem to figure out what the implicit I need to import is.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you complete the request with just a `Cluster` instead of a `List[Cluster]`, does it compile? Is the implicit jsonFormat for `cluster` in `JsonImplicits`?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  Same error.

Comment: It probably can't find the `JsonFormat` for `Cluster`. In the above `impCluster` is not `implicit` though it should be. Is that a copy/paste error, or is that what's in your code?

Comment: That was it.  Make it the answer and I'll mark it for you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure that the implicit `JsonFormat` for the `Cluster` type is in scope, so that `SprayJsonSupport` knows how to marshall that type. With that you should automatically get support for marshaling `List[Cluster]` from the default formats.

In the posted code `val impCluster = jsonFormat2(Cluster)` defines the `JsonFormat`, but it is not marked as `implicit`, so the typeclass cannot be implicitly resolved. Changing it to

```
implicit val impCluster = jsonFormat2(Cluster)
```

should fix the issue.