# Spray Form Data to Case Class

Tags: scala, spray

New to Scala to go easy on me!

I'm using spray atm and posting requests in. I'm looking to convert the post data to a case class but it throws an error `could not find implicit value for parameter um: spray.httpx.unmarshalling.FromRequestUnmarshaller`. What might I be doing incorrect? The Documentation is a bit confusing.

```
post {
    entity(as[TextMessage]) { txt =>
        println(txt.body)
        complete("")
    }
}
```

And my Case Class `case class TextMessage( body: String, from: String)`

From the docs this should work off the bat.

Ideas?

Edit: The data isn't being posted as JSON it's posted as form data i.e. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the JsonFormat for the TextMessage type is in the scope, so that Spray cand find out how to marshall that type.

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20408734/could-not-find-implicit-value-for-parameter-marshaller-spray-httpx-marshalling)

Comment: The response isn't being posted to me in JSON it's form data's  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't parsed form data with spray so I don't know if easier way exists but I would use `formFields` directive.

```
val textMessageEntity = formFields('body, 'from).as(TextMessage)

post {
    textMessageEntity { txt =>
        println(txt.body)
        complete("")
    }
}
```

Here is more information about `formFields` directive: http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/form-field-directives/formFields/