# could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type ^

Tags: scala, spray-json

I am trying to write a test for a Post request

here is my code :

```
val request = CreateLinkRequest(token = Some(validToken),billing_ref_id = Some("123"), store_id = Some("123"), agent_id = Some("123"))

val endPoint = Uri(this.serverRootUrl + "path").toString
val post = Post(endPoint, request)
val pipeline = jsonAsStringPipeline(post)
val responseContents = Await.ready(pipeline, atMost = callMaxWaitDuration)
```

But this doesnt compile, I keep getting this error :

```
Error:(156, 20) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type spray.httpx.marshalling.Marshaller[CreateLinkSpec.this.CreateLinkRequest]
    val post = Post(endPoint, request)
               ^
Error:(156, 20) not enough arguments for method apply: (implicit evidence$1: 

spray.httpx.marshalling.Marshaller[CreateLinkSpec.this.CreateLinkRequest])spray.http.HttpRequest in class RequestBuilder.
Unspecified value parameter evidence$1.
    val post = Post(endPoint, request)
                   ^
```

What does this mean?

How can I fix it ?

EDIT:
this is the json in the body :

```
{ token:"123", billing_ref_id:"123", store_id:"123", agent_id:"123"}
```

and this is the object for it in the code:

```
private final case class CreateLinkRequest(
    token: Option[String] = Some(validToken),
    billing_ref_id: Option[String] = Some(Random.alphanumeric.take(10).mkString),
    agent_id: Option[String] = Some(Random.alphanumeric.take(3).mkString),
    store_id: Option[String] = Some(Random.alphanumeric.take(3).mkString)
    )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [could not find implicit value for parameter marshaller: spray.httpx.marshalling.ToResponseMarshaller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20408734/could-not-find-implicit-value-for-parameter-marshaller-spray-httpx-marshalling)

Comment: unfortunately this does not solve my problem

Comment: How does your POST route look like? Does it require JSON in the body?

Comment: yes, it requires json in the body, see edited question for content json object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to call `Post` method which takes `implicit Marshaller` as parameter. Note that implicit parameters don't have to be provided as long as the compiler can find one in the scope (check this for more info about implicits: [Where does Scala look for implicits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits))

However, your code doesn't have any implicit Marshaller defined so the compiler doesn't know how to convert your `case class` into the `HttpEntity`.

In your case you want it to be converted into the `HttpEntity` with `Content-Type: application/json`. To do that you just need to define: `implicit val CreateLinkRequestMarshaller: Marshaller[CreateLinkRequest]`. This tells scala how to convert your `case class` into the `HttpEntity`.

You also want it to be passed to the context as JSON, so we are going to define our JsonProtocol, i.e. `MyJsonProtocol`.

```
package test

import spray.http.HttpEntity
import spray.http._
import spray.json._
import spray.httpx.marshalling.{Marshaller, MarshallingContext}
import test.TestMarshaller.CreateLinkRequest


object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit def createLinkRequestFormat: JsonFormat[CreateLinkRequest] = jsonFormat4(CreateLinkRequest)
}

object TestMarshaller extends App {
  import MyJsonProtocol._

  case class CreateLinkRequest(token: Option[String], billing_ref_id: Option[String], store_id: Option[String], agent_id: Option[String])

  implicit val CreateLinkRequestMarshaller: Marshaller[CreateLinkRequest] = new Marshaller[CreateLinkRequest] {
    override def apply(value: CreateLinkRequest, ctx: MarshallingContext): Unit = {
      val entity = HttpEntity(MediaTypes.`application/json`, value.toJson.compactPrint)
      ctx.marshalTo(entity)
    }
  }

  // Here goes your test
}
```

Note that you can define these implicits somewhere else, e.g. a `package` and then just import it in the test class. This would be better because you will certainly want to reuse the Marshaller.